# Download large file from Skydrive to Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, onedrive

Am having some trouble with the SkyDrive download process and hoping you can help me.

Following the standard SkyDrive API & examples, I've set up a page that browses the SkyDrive folder structure, lets User click on a file, prompt to download, and it all works correctly.

Where I'm having trouble is when the file downloaded is large, I get the OutOfMemoryException thrown at around the 100Mb mark.

Dennis speaks on this problem here http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/2-things-you-should-consider but it relates to a direct URL download, not via the SkyDrive architecture.

I've tried extracting the URL from SkyDrive and doing the direct download that way but haven't had any success.

Here is the code I'm using - the "item" object is of type SkyDriveItem, having iterated through a folders content and selected this file.

```
LiveConnectClient downloadClient = new LiveConnectClient(App.Session);
                    try
                    {
                        downloadClient.DownloadCompleted += new EventHandler<LiveDownloadCompletedEventArgs>(downloadClient_DownloadCompleted);
                        downloadClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new EventHandler<LiveDownloadProgressChangedEventArgs>(downloadClient_DownloadProgressChanged);
                        downloadClient.DownloadAsync(item.ID + "/content", item);
```

This will work fine  when the file isn't too large, but as mentioned, select a big file (>100Mb) and it dies with the OutOfMemory exception.

Any pointers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you using to download? WebClient, BackgroundTransferRequest etc?

Comment: Hi Jon, I've updated the question to display the code I've used. It's the standard SkyDrive objects , and it works great when the files are smaller.

Comment: I do not know if they have a download size limit but assuming they do, then you could get the url to the file and download it in parts with a WebRequest using the range values and I would think it would work.

Comment: Jon, have you been able to get this URL from Skydrive that is pointing directly at the file? I've followed the SDK doco but cannot get the actual URL that will represent the file - it always seems to load up the HTML Skydrive viewer no matter what params or config I pass in.

Comment: I am using the REST API, so I get the URL as a parameter when I get the FolderContents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved - While I was never able to use the downloadClient.DownloadAsync() method to download large files, playing with the downloadClient.getAsync() and using the Pre-Authenticated URL via a regular Stream downloader does the trick.